# Opencv: Create black window and write text to it

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there a simple way to create a black image file and write text to it?  I have tried  simply creating a Mat using

`cv::Mat pic = cv::Mat::zeros(250,250,CV_8U)`

and then write text to it using the command

`cv::putText(pic, "some text",cv::Point(50,50), CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,          cv::Scalar(0,0,255,0),1,8,false);`

Do I need a different type instead of `CV_8U` in my initial matrix of zeros?  Or am I missing something else here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are creating single-channel image but coloring the text with red. Possible solution:

1. Create three-channel matrix
   `cv::Mat pic = cv::Mat::zeros(250,250,CV_8UC3)`
2. or set the text color to white
   `cv::putText(pic, "some text",cv::Point(50,50), CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,    cv::Scalar(255),1,8,false);`